# Which preposition to use with "diagnose"

Tags: prepositions

I had an English exam today. One of the questions was fill in the gaps. It was like:

> Doctors diagnosed him **with/ for** hyperactivity.

So should the gap be *with* or *for*? I checked Google and there are a lot of examples of each.

Comment: [Many](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diagnose) [dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/diagnose) will tell you immediately that the correct preposition is ‘with’.

Comment: yes - and you should only trust a google source if it is adequately referenced.

Comment: Both are correct in their appropriate contexts. See usage examples to understand the difference. "Minorities, young people take longer to **diagnose for cancer**, ...;" "Texas Chiropractors Seek Ability to **Diagnose for Spine, Muscle System**;" "Being able to test and **diagnose for diabetes** is quite challenging and very difficult for most doctors because the human blood sugar level is not ..." Get it?

Comment: Why close the question?

Comment: Since I am a physician of over 30 years' experience, I think my expertise counts for something. Barrie is correct. The comments from Janus and Peter are generally also correct. "Diagnose for (a disease)" is simply not correct, not even in the manner suggested, as if _diagnose_ was somehow synonymous with _test_. It is not. Nor is the usage changing. Medical jargon is specific, as it must be. _Diagnose_ means to definitively identify a disease, period. You may diagnose a disease (no preposition), or diagnose a patient _as having_ or _with_ a disease. That's it, and that's all.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg 
Makes perfect sense, agrees with your definition, which is what the dictionaries too generally provide: 
"... there is provided a system for analysis of liquid or semi-solid body secretion samples obtained from human patients to **diagnose for** the presence or absence of abnormalities in the patient, ..."
*Alcohol Oxidoreductases—Advances in Research and Application: 2013* p.65 -- [emphasis mine] Notice the significance of the preposition here.

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=w77cZvUTuugC&lpg=PA65&dq=%22diagnose%20for%22&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=%22diagnose%20for%22&f=false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Diagnosed with* is by far the most frequent and it is what I, as a speaker of British English, would use. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 3,215 records for *diagnosed with* and 20 for *diagnosed for*. I haven’t looked at the contexts in which *diagnosed for* is used, but they clearly must be quite exceptional.

Comment: In a regular Google search (and I would imagine also in Google Books), most of those hits are in cases like, “She was diagnosed for the first time”, “She had been mis-diagnosed for four years”, etc., where ‘for’ belongs to a separate phrase.

Comment: It’s much the same in the COCA, but it does include these: ‘At the time I got diagnosed for it I didn' it think of this as stress’, ‘Andrea had been diagnosed for depression and hospitalized’, ‘be diagnosed for exactly the form of hypertension that you have’, ‘when I've been diagnosed for cancer’, ‘All patients in the study had been diagnosed for diabetes’.

Comment: There were some of those in Google General, too. To me, those are quite unambiguously ungrammatical, but they appear to come from native speakers, so obviously it must be grammatical to some speakers, somewhere.

Comment: I too find *diagnosed **for*** to be ungrammatical. I wonder where those examples are coming from. Strange.

Comment: I think some people use "diagnosed for" when maybe they really should be using "tested for" ... that is, if you go in for a diagnosis to see **whether or not** you have cancer, you are being "diagnosed *for* cancer". If it turns out that you actually **do** have cancer, you will then have been "diagnosed *with* cancer". (This could account for some of Barrie's examples, but not all of them ... I think one or two of them are just wrong.)

Comment: In fact, googling immediately reveals some uses of "diagnosed for" which do have this meaning: for example, *"Where do I go to get diagnosed for Asperger syndrome?"* and *"How to Get Diagnosed for Adult ADHD"* are two hits on the first page Google gives for "diagnosed for".

Comment: @PeterShor – Aha! That explains it. That is an odd usage that I can’t say I’ve ever come across before—all those questions asking about how or where to be diagnosed for something just struck me as utterly bewildering before, but your explanation makes them clear as day. A verbally strange day, but a day nonetheless.

Comment: I would venture further that "diagnosed for", as a synonym for "tested for", is working its way into the language.

Comment: Both prepositions are Okay. First the doctors diagnose **for** something; if the test is confirmed, you say the patient was diagnosed **with** the something.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, **Diagnosed with** is the correct option.

> By the time he was diagnosed with cancer, it was already too late.

Diagnosed of is not used, as far as I understand.However a common usage would be **Diagnosis of**

> Diagnosis of his cancer happened very late.

It may be also used as a headline or header.

> Symptoms and Diagnosis of Cancer

Another very common usage is **Diagnosed as**

> He was diagnosed as schizophrenic.
>
> He was diagnosed as suffering from cancer.

Comment: You may wish to edit & clarify your answer. Your first sentence doesn't make sense. "... Diagnosed of *and* Diagnosed with *is* the correct option". You then later contradict it by saying "Diagnosed of is not used".

Comment: Corrected, hope it works.