# How is the predicate of the verb 'to diagnose' formed?

Tags: verb-patterns

So often nowadays one hears people say *He was diagnosed with walliballi disease*.

Is this grammatically correct? What does a doctor diagnose? My own instinct, supported by the OED is that a doctor diagnoses an illness, or a medical condition - he/she does not diagnose a person.

The OED definition* of the verb, with examples is:

> a. trans. To make a diagnosis of (a disease), to distinguish and
>   determine its nature from its symptoms; to recognize and identify by
>   careful observation.
>
> 1861   A. Wynter Our Social Bees 339,   I was enabled to diagnose the
>   complaint at once.
>
> 1877   F. T. Roberts Handbk. Med. (ed. 3) I. 231   Articular
>   rheumatism has also to be diagnosed from the other forms.
>
> 1887   Homeop. World 1 Nov. 497,   I diagnosed chronic jaundice.

So can it be correct to say *He was diagnosed with...*?

Would it not be more correct to say:

*He was found by diagnosis to have....*.

Or what would be an alternative way of saying the same thing?

*It would be less than honest not to include the caveat in the most recent edition of OED: 'This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1895)' (Contributed by Edwin Ashworth)

Had the OP been aware of such caveat he would naturally have included it. It does not appear in the current online edition. And whilst on the subject of 'honesty', have the editors of this post ever actually seen such a caveat in print? (OP's response).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25221/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-how-is-the-predicate-of-the-verb-to-diagnose-for).

Comment: related: [Which preposition to use with “diagnose”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/which-preposition-to-use-with-diagnose/124800#124800) and [Is the correct usage of “Diagnose (verb)” losing its ground?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/is-the-correct-usage-of-diagnose-verb-losing-its-ground)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've read that lot. But I still maintain that one needs to look to the way the word is used in other related languages as well as English. It makes no sense, in my view, to *diagnose a person* - unless it be to state that he she is an example of *homo-sapiens*.

Comment: There is a doctor in the house who is equally horrified at how *diagnosed* has been treated in recent times. :) http://english.stackexchange.com/a/269571/44619

Answer (score 3):

OLD lists the following usages with the verb ***[diagnose](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/diagnose)***:

> - to say exactly what an illness or the cause of a problem is:

Usages:

> - ***diagnose (something)*** *The test is used to diagnose a variety of diseases.*
> - ***diagnose something as something*** *The illness was diagnosed as cancer.*
> - ***diagnose somebody with something*** *He has recently been diagnosed with angina.*
> - ***diagnose somebody (as) something*** *He was diagnosed (as) a diabetic when he was 64.*
> - ***diagnose somebody + adj./noun*** *He was diagnosed (a) diabetic.*

and ***[diagnosis](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/diagnosis):***

> - diagnosis (of something) the act of discovering or identifying the exact cause of an illness or a problem.

Usages:

> - ***diagnosis of*** lung cancer
> - They are waiting for the ***doctor's diagnosis.***
> - An accurate ***diagnosis was made*** after a series of tests.

- ***He was found by diagnosis to have*** does not sound appropriate as a sentence, ***he was diagnosed with*** or **the diagnosis was** are more appropriate alternatives.

> - ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diagnosed%20with%2Cdiagnosed%20as&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiagnosed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiagnosed%20as%3B%2Cc0): diagnosed with, diagnosed as***

Answer (score 2):

The supplement to the *OED* records an earlier example of "diagnosis," from *Phil Inductive Sci*, 1840:  "The Characteristick has been termed by some English botanists the diagnosis of plants...."  Not the diagnosis of plant diseases.   Thus I submit by the *OED*'s own historical criterion, "diagnose" may take as its object either the patients (in this case, floral) or their maladies.

That said the reported incidence these days of walliballi disease is nothing short of alarming.

Comment: +1 Interesting observation. My OP has elsewhere generated more heat than light. But your answer carries a useful validity.

Comment: So much better than my usual useless validity.

Comment: I should have said *luminescence*!

Answer (score 1):

I think "diagnose" takes a patient as its indirect object and a disease as its direct object.  "diagnose Hannah with malaria" / "diagnose malaria in Hannah" is parallel with "supply Hannah with an antidote" / "supply an antidote to Hannah".  As with other indirect object constructions, the result of the event is that the indirect object has the direct object.  Here, after the diagnosis, Hannah has the disease.

Comment: No. In 'They diagnosed her as having TB', 'her' is as much a DO as in 'The judge found her guilty'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, and as much a direct object as "The judge sent her the verdict"?

Comment: +1 You have added significantly to the debate here. *Supply* would seem to me to be an example of a 'ditransitive verb'? (I am not a linguistics scholar in the way that @John Lawler is). But this seems to me to boil the whole matter down to whether *diagnose* is *[ditransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)*; i.e. can it take two objects which refer to a theme and a recipient.

Comment: @Greg Lee The judge sent her the verdict <==> The judge sent the verdict to her. // The judge found her guilty <=/=> *The judge found guilty to [/for] her.  // M-W defines 'transitive' as: 
grammar of a verb : _having or taking a direct object_ and lists both V + disease and V + patient as [transitive usages](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnose): **diagnose** transitive verb
1
a :  to recognize (as a disease) by signs and symptoms
b :  to diagnose a disease or condition in <diagnosed the patient>

Comment: I like this idea in principle, but it requires extending the group of verbs that can take indirect objects without direct objects beyond the single verb _tell_. Additionally, when indirect object constructions are passivised, any other closely related adverbial phrase can usually be put either before or after the agent without much difference beyond a certain level of clumsiness (“The book was given [to her] by John [to her]”), but “Hannah was diagnosed by the doctor with malaria”/“Malaria was diagnosed by the doctor in Hannah” just sound downright _wrong_ to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Indirect object alone: "supply hospitals (with drugs)", "refuse Henry (any help)", "mail the staff (a memo)".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Only because you have become conditioned to hearing it said incorrectly in English. How do you say it in Danish? My bet is that the verb *diagnose* takes an illness as its object.

Comment: @WS2 I had to look it up, because I couldn’t figure out how I _would_ use it in Danish myself. According to [_The Danish Dictionary_](http://ordnet.dk/ddo_en/dict?query=diagnosticere&set_language=en), the object of _diagnosticere_ can be either the disease or the patient in Danish, too (and I would add that, as in English, both is also an option).

Comment: So it's a ditransitive verb in Danish. It surprises me. It is not the case in French. I've asked @Mari-Lou about the Italian.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case of [back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation). It's a well-established process that happens in pretty much all languages. If *diagnose* is not grammatical, then neither is *edit* or *pea*.

Comment: Wait, *pea*? I don't get that one. *Plea*, maybe?

Comment: You're missing an important point here. The only changes that are allowed to be made in English usage are those made _before_ X was alive (X being the Grammar / Word Usage / Spelling / Punctuation ... Czar).

Comment: @DanBron *pea* is a back-formation from *pease* (interpreted as a plural).

Comment: I didn't know that!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the earliest attestations of *edit* are after the death of John Dryden, who invented the ban on the passive voice.

Comment: *Diagnose* does indeed seem to be a back-formation, but as such it has a clear meaning as *distinguishing and determining* a disease - not the subjection of a human to a determination of what disease(s) from which he may be suffering.

Comment: @WS2 How can an individual decide at which point the process of changes in usage became unacceptable? Most of us gladly accept 100-year-old usages that are still current, but did the people who were in our shoes 100 years ago feel the same way? Almost all modern dictionaries – perhaps all those with a sensible number of pages – accept these modern usages for 'diagnose' (and OED will do when the editors catch up). Not to do so is perpetuating the etymological fallacy.

Comment: Are you saying that the passive voice is no longer used?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it is confirmed by myself that the passive voice is never used ;-) I was playing along with your comment about a grammar czar. Dryden is a favorite whipping boy of Linguistics 101 lecturers.

Comment: Now that _is_ a coincidence – I came across the intransitive sense of 'vapulate' (obsolete) once: to be whipped. Does that mean it was an anti-deponent verb?